# Android: Append not shown ActionItems to Icon instead of Context Menu

Tags: android

I found an example how to use a context menu with actionBar. This example waits for clicks on the phones menu button. But I want to have it appended to the icon or better the activity name. thanks

```
  public class menu extends Activity {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragen, menu);
           return true;
        }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
..
```

Comment: Please consider clarifying what you mean by "But I want to have it appended to the icon or better the activity name". For example, what is "it" that you want "appended to the icon"? What icon are you referring to? What are you considering to be "the activity name"?

Comment: have a look here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html . After the logo and title comes an drop down menu indicator. I want to use this menu instead of having a context menu activated by the hw menu button. everything from the hw button menu should go there (by default its everything from the menu that is not showAsAction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the logo and title comes an drop down menu indicator.

That has nothing to do with `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `onOptionsItemSelected()`. To set up that `Spinner`:

1. Get your `ActionBar` via `getActionBar()`
2. Call `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)` on the `ActionBar`
3. Call `setListNavigationCallbacks()` on the `ActionBar` with your `SpinnerAdapter` and a listener object to be notified when the user makes a selection change in the `Spinner`